# Sticky footer not working with extended html in django?

Tags: python, django, html, sticky-footer

Im working with django and im trying to put the a sticky footer but its not working. Im inserting the footer on the basic.html and it always gets on top of the content of the extended page like login.html. If I try to insert the footer on the extended files it starts working again but I dont want to replicate the footer code through all the pages. I presume that its because django loads the window size on basic.html first making the absolute positioning of the footer stay on top of the finished page (after rendering on login.html content). But if I try a normal paragraph after the code its works without a problem.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-Voup2lBiiyZYkRto2XWqbzxHXwzcm4A5RfdfG6466bu5LqjwwrjXCMBQBLMWh7qR" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'css/basic.css' %}" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'css/register.css' %}" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'css/main.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/Projects-Clean.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">

    <title>
        Django Sample Site - {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{% static 'images/logo.svg' %}" alt="logo" id="logo">
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'Anime:index' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'Anime:fullAnimeList' %}">List</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Genre</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline mr-auto">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
                            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="{% url 'Anime:login' %}">Login<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="{% url 'Anime:register' %}">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                            {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
                                <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="{% url 'Anime:aradmin' %}">Admin</a>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="{% url 'Anime:profile' request.user.username %}">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
                            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="{% url 'Anime:logout' %}">Logout<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="flex-box">
                {% block pagecontent %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    <p>ola</p>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>Copyright 2018 Rui Alves & Diogo Crava</p>
    </footer>
    </main>


</body>
</html>


    { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

html { 
    background: url('/static/images/background.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

body, div {
    background-color: transparent;
}

nav {
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid #5fa0da;
    border-radius: 20px 20px;
}

.footer {
    color: #5fa0da;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

#logo {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.flex-box {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid #5fa0da;
    border-radius: 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: did you try `position:fixed`

Comment: Honestly, I tried everything! But Ill try that gain :P

Comment: I think it gets on top of extended content because it set to `position absolute`, so it considers the parent `body` as a grid wrapper... if you add `position: relative` to body it'll work, but it's not convenient. I suggest that you fix it to the bottom